# MainWindow get access to methods

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf project without StartupUri. I set the MainWindow as **TestWindow** in app.cs. But i can't use the **DoNothing** method. How can i access to methods of TestWindow?

```
MainWindow.DoNothing(); //No such method. Get error when try to build
```

Project:

**TestWindow.cs**

```
public partial class TestWindow : BaseWindow
{
...
    public void DoNothing()
    {
        return;
    }
...
}
```

**app.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"/>
```

**app.cs**

```
...
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e); 
    MainWindow = new TestWindow();
}
...
```

Comment: Cast it to your class `((TheClass)ThePropOrVarWhichTypeIsBaseClassOfTheClass).TheClassMethod()`

Comment: But if you need this ... then something is wrong with your architecture

Comment: I have a tray application. All the time it does not need a window. I set the MainWindow and hide it. When new data arrived i just show the MainWindow and update information.

I don't need a empty window when my try app loads

Comment: See [this example](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/working-with-app-xaml/) of how to change the StartupUri to a code-behind function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast `MainWindow` to your type:

```
(MainWindow as TestWindow)?.DoNothing();
```

Or store a reference to the `TestWindow` in a variable of your own and access the window directly using this one:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly TestWindow testWindow = new TestWindow();

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        MainWindow = testWindow;
        ...
        testWindow.BeginInit();
    }
}
```